# How do I write a header to an existing CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a directory with a bunch of CSV files with no headers.

I tried doing it like this:

```
def add_headers_to_csvs
  csvs = Dir["#{@dir_name}/#{@state}/*.csv"]
  csvs.each do |csv_file|
    CSV.open(csv_file, "a+", write_headers: true, headers: ["Company_Name","Website","Street_Address", "City", "State", "Zip", "Phone","Email"]) do |csv|
    end
  end
end
```

I was hoping that the `write_headers` and `headers:` option would work and it doesn't.

How do I accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just re-open them in place, especially in append mode. You'll need to open a new file, write the headers, then append all of the original data as well.

Normally you'd do this with a temporary file of some sort:

```
CSV.open(csv_file + '.tmp', 'w', write_headers: true, headers: [ ...]) do |dest|
  # Transpose original data
  CSV.open(csv_file) do |source|
    source.each do |row|
      dest << row
    end
  end
end

# Swap new version for old
File.rename(csv_file + '.tmp', csv_file)
```

Now you'll absolutely want to have **backups of your original data** in case something goes horribly wrong.

Comment: Uggghh...this is what I was trying to avoid. Just to add 1 row at the top, I have to rebuild the entire CSV file? There no way to just stick a new row at position `i[0]` in the CSV file?

Comment: That's not how files work, you can't "insert" data and have bytes magically move around. Appending is easy. Pre-pending involves more work, usually a re-write of the whole file.

Comment: Interesting. Ok...I will consider this approach.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked like a charm. It actually worked much faster than I  thought it would. Thanks much!

Comment: Good to hear! Yeah, it is surprising how fast some things can be. Computers are pretty amazing these days.